# Docusign API- License Management for Auto User provisioning

Tags: docusignapi

I am implementing auto user provisioning with Docusign REST API.
When a user is created, Does it occupies license.
Can you please point to documentation or give me an idea that how license management is done from User Provisioning perspective(if any).

Answer (score 0):

You will have buy a plan that supports multiple users in your account.

You can find more information [here](https://www.docusign.com/b/products-and-pricing)